# Set system font in LXDE?

Tags: fonts, lxde

I want to set the system font in LXDE, but I can't find where the setting is. This is what the Font tab looks like in lxappearance. As you can see, there is no combo for selecting the font:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found it - the "Default font" combo is (mis)placed in the "Widget" tab. I really don't understand why they didn't put it in the "Font" tab.

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer post.

Comment: Could the reason be because the font setting in Widgets is only for Widgets, not the entire system?