# How to set system fonts as noto?

Tags: fonts

I have installed google noto fonts in /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto .and execute the command:

```
fc-cache -fv
```

1.How to know which type of fonts is being used in my debian8.1?
2.How to set google noto fonts to be used in my debian8.1?How to set the configuration file /etc/fonts/fonts.conf ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Set system font in LXDE?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161668/set-system-font-in-lxde):

The "Default font" combo is (mis)placed in the "Widget" tab. I really don't understand why they didn't put it in the "Font" tab.

Comment: Well, the OP never asked for LXDE-specific instructions. The OP wanted to change the *system default* serif, sans and mono fonts. Changing LXDE settings will not affect font selection in other applications such as Firefox, Evolution etc.

Answer (score 5):

To know what default fonts are being used on your system, run the commands

```
$ fc-match sans-serif
$ fc-match serif
$ fc-match monospace
```

They should give you the system default sans-serif, serif and monospace fonts respectively.

To set the system defaults to Google's Noto fonts, you need to edit the [fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) configuration files. For details see the [fontconfig documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html). For a readymade config file, see [this repo](https://github.com/ayanb280/noto-on-linux).